# Difference between "random want" and "whim"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between the words *random want* and *whim*?

The definition of **whim** can be easily found in the [dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/whim):

> a sudden wish to do or have something, especially when it is something
>   unusual or unnecessary

**Random want** is not on the dictionary. It turns out to be just two words combined together. But it seems to me to have nearly the same meaning as *whim*.

I came across this word chunk in the [phrase](http://www.efl.ru/forum/threads/53549/#m616413) made up by a native American:

> They thought the problem to be settled was how on earth to get posters
>   to understand that CONTEXT is not just some **random WANT** on the part of
>   those who would like to answer, but an ABSOLUTE REQUIREMENT.

But later in the discussion the native speaker writes:

> random want fits better than whim

, which suggest that there is some difference for him between the words *whim* and *random want*.

So, what is the difference?

Comment: Seems to me that you've answered your own question! It all boils down to the difference between what you wish for and what you want.

Comment: @Ambar From the dictionary: `wish`= `a desire or a feeling that you want to do sth or have sth`; `want` = `something that you need or want`. But `random want` makes `want` more close to `whim`, doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of dialectal differences, but it seems rather odd for OP's "native American" to have used the word *want* rather than *wish* or *desire*. But in any case, *arbitrary request* seems far better when contrasting with *absolute requirement*.

Comment: **1** It may be worth bearing in mind that the noun "want" is also something that one lacks "For the want of a nail the shoe was lost." **2** *Random want is not in the dictionary. It turns out to be just two words combined* - - so is random whim...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasper Loy's answer gave me some ideas. I want to lay out some elaboration in this answer.

**random want** is what happens by chance, not according to the plan.

There are several explanation for **whim** in different dictionaries:

[**OALD**](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/whim): a sudden wish to do or have something, especially when it is something unusual or unnecessary

[**Cambridge**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/whim?q=whim): a sudden wish or idea, especially one that cannot be reasonably explained

**Macmillan**: a sudden feeling that you must have or must do something. This word often suggests that what someone wants is not important.

So, **whim** carries the idea suddenness, unusualness, being unnecessary, without reasonable explanation and usually not being important.

Taking all this into account, it seems to me that **whim** can't be according to the plan (I don't see how something sudden, unnecessary and not important can be on the plan).

This means that **whim** is **random want** with some additional features of being sudden and unnecessary. Whereas **random want** per se doesn't have the idea of being unnecessary (still random, it might be useful), or sudden, or unimportant (it may turnt out to be important when this want appears).

Answer (score 6):

I think the difference here boils down to the differences between these words:

- need (require)
- want (desire but do not need)
- whim (sudden or random desire)

The original quote is saying that context is a need, not just a want. When discussing requirements it is normal to prioritize according to needs and wants. That is the distinction that the author is making here.

A whim, on the other hand, is not as strong a desire as a want, and using the word "whim" softens the nature of the desire for context. Thus, the author wanted to keep the word "want" for its specific purpose in this context.

Comment: Why **want** is `desire but no need`? The dictionary gives the following definition of **want**: something that you need or want.

Comment: @ovgolovin: When comparing desires, as the quote is doing, a requirement is a NEED (it must be fulfilled) and something which is desired but not strictly needed is a WANT. In the broader sense, you usually WANT what you NEED, but when making the comparison, the terminology is more precise.

Comment: That's Mr. Economics talking, not Mr. Shiny ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's not so much that the overall meaning is different.

You could say that a *random want* is a *whim* if you wanted.

The problem with the context you give is that the writer has emphasised the wrong word. The writer seems to want to make it clear that the the need for context is not *random* and so should have emphasised that word, rather than *want*. They do want context, and presumably for very good reasons. So the want is not random.

Put in this light, I think it is better to use the phrase ***random** want* over *whim* because it has hard sounds in it, which allows the writer to express their frustration better.

*Whim* is a soft word that conjures up ideas of whimsy and so would not fit in well with the anger the writer is trying to diffuse.

Comment: +1. I think an additional difference between a *random want* and a *whim* is permanence. To me, it seems that a *whim* is a desire that you're quite likely not to have tomorrow, while a *random want* is something that you desire for no particularly good reason, but which you will quite possibly still want tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks! It explains why the author preferred **random want**.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you provide the author is using want in the nounified jargon-based sense of technical requirements.  A requirement for a system being designed that is nice to have, but is not essential, would be a WANT.  Whereas a NEED or a MUST HAVE needs to be implemented for the system to be successful.

Whim is a good synonym for what is being described by the author, but it lacks the semantics of technical requirements.